# How to find duplicate adjacent cells in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns in Excel (like below) and I would like to identify (conditionally format) any rows that are exactly the same.

As you can see 326.001 1,000 HOUR are identical for the first 3 rows, I would like to highlight or mark these rows so I can see that they are not unique.

```
+---------+------------+
|   ID    |  INTERVAL  |
+---------+------------+
| 326.001 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.001 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.001 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.001 | 3,000 HOUR |
| 326.002 | 1 MONTH    |
| 326.002 | 1 YEAR     |
| 326.002 | 5 YEAR     |
| 326.002 | 500 HOUR   |
| 326.002 | 500 HOUR   |
| 326.002 | 500 HOUR   |
| 326.002 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.002 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.002 | 1,000 HOUR |
| 326.002 | 3,000 HOUR |
| 326.009 | 3 MONTH    |
| 326.009 | 1 YEAR     |
| 326.01  | 3 MONTH    |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS() as your formula in the conditional formatting.

Comment: I found a simple solution. I just concatenated the 2 cells into 1 and I used the Conditional Formatting -> Duplicate Values to highlight the duplicates.

Comment: Did you try my formula, it would work without the helper column.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a third column: EqualityTest, with a formula such as:
=AND([@ID]=A5,[@INTERVAL]=B5)

This assumes the data is sorted.

The above formula is for row 5, with ID and Interval in columns A and B. Copy-Paste the formula down, and apply conditional formatting to highlight False for unique values.

Answer (score 0):

So use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10000,$A2,$B$2:$B$10000,$B2)>0
```

It will return true for any that has duplicates in both columns.  This formula does not care if the data is sorted or not.

Answer (score 0):

qroberts,

I'm not clear on your question.

If you're actually attempting to *remove* duplicate rows, Excel offers that as a function on the basic ribbon bar for the "Data" ribbon: the button (!) is "Remove Duplicates" in the "Data Tools" section on the "Data" ribbon.

If, instead, you are looking for a highlighter which will identify duplicates, things are a bit more complicated, as you need a macro which will find duplicates and then turn on some form of formatting/highlighting (I suggest formatting a background color).

For a macro which will highlight duplicates, we need to hear a bit more to understand your needs. If you have two different sets of duplicates, do you want them highlighted to different colors?  If the number of duplicate sets 
gets large, this could be a problem.

As another poster has noted, it also matters whether your candidate set is sorted. A full range search for duplicates would be an interesting bit of coding.

Comment: Not looking to remove the duplicates. I want to be able to identify which rows are identical and once I do that I will need to edit the INTERVAL column so they are no longer identical. This is a sample of a larger dataset with more columns that I am importing into a database. One of the database rules is that you cannot have an ID with more than one of the same INTERVAL type, which is what I need to change once I identify the 'duplicates'.